# how to execute maven project through pom.xml file

Tags: maven, webdriver

I am new to maven and generated maven pom.XML file. I need to execute my project using pom XML file

Steps I followed are as below

1. right click on the pom XML
2. click on mvn clean.

I am getting build successful. After that if i compile or run the pom.XML file I am getting goal not to set error.

Can you please suggest how can i run my project using pom XML file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. right click on the pom XML
2. click on maven install.

or

set the goal "mvn install"

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. I am using testng framework, i need to generate html reports for that am using reportng api, velicoty api, guice jar and in the xml file i added listeners code after run my pom xml am getting testoutput folder but in the index.html displays html code instead of report what i need to do ? can you please suggest..

Comment: Hi, Which application you use to open "Index.html"? Please open that in a web-browser.

Comment: Hi i am opens from test output folder from testng if i open in web browser the executed passed testcases status displays in skipped status in web browser

Comment: I think your "testng" configuration may be incorrect in pom.xml. from where the testng testcase read inputs. Is it need a specific base folder. Plesae read from http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html